# Make case insensitive GraphQL query

Tags: node.js, neo4j, graphql

I am using GraphQL query language and Neo4j database. In database I have different names and when I make GraphQL query with arguments to fetch some data from database I have to take care of lowercase and uppercase letters. For Example when I have

```
{ Employee(name: "Stewart Irma"){
    name
  }
}
```

this working, but when I have

```
{ Employee(name: "stewart irma") {
    name
  }
}
```

this not working.
How to make reslovers to be case-insensitive.

Answer (score 3):

In your GraphQL schema, you need to create a query type that includes a case-insensitive cypher query on the name parameter:

```
schema {
  query: QueryType
}

type QueryType {
  EmployeeNameQuery(name:String!): [Employee] @cypher(statement:"MATCH (n:Employee) WHERE LOWER(n.name) CONTAINS LOWER($name) RETURN n;")
}
```

Then you can query this way:

```
{ EmployeeNameQuery(name: "stewart irma") {
    name
  }
}
```